# issues retrieving character array data

Tags: c++, arrays, database, fstream, seek

I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm undertaking this project that I've been trying to rack my brain around for a little while.

Basically, I want to have 10 records of users in this "database." Right now I have salary and year_hired as double and int respectively. I want to change them into an array eventually.

I'm facing a couple of issues here:

1. When the function outputLine calls the data to be viewed from one employee, everything shows up perfectly fine except for the "name section", which comes up with gibberish. See below:

```
Enter employee ID (1-10) or 0 to end input:
5
Enter name, salary, then year hired:
test
130000
2009
Enter employee ID (1-10) or 0 to end input:
0
Enter choice 2 to choose employees:
2

Enter your choice:
1 - update an account
2 - add a new account
3 - end program
1
Enter account to update(1-10): 5
5
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
130000
2009
```

The code for showing the name is as follows. I also included my struct for insight:

```
struct employee {
int year_hired;
double salary;
char name[30];
int ID;
void outputLine(ostream &output, employee &employed)
{
output << employed.getId() << endl
    << employed.getName() << endl
    << employed.getsal() << endl
    << employed.getYearHired() << endl;

}
void setname(string n) {
    const char *ptr = &name[30];

    ptr = n.c_str();
```

2. When I try to use my program's ability to "update" an account, the salary I enter does not change the salary stored.
   See the copy and pasted data below for reference:

```
Enter account to update(1-10): 5
5
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
130000
2009

Enter salary: 20

Enter your choice:
1 - update an account
2 - add a new account
3 - end program
1
Enter account to update(1-10): 5
5
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
130000
2009
```

3. When the user is prompted to "add" a new account, it checks to see if that account has information. Even if I haven't set that account up yet, the program will tell me that the account has information stored. I have a section of my code dedicated to construction 10 blank records for input, but it doesn't seem that it really does anything.

Section that creates 10 blank records:

```
            ofstream outdatabase("database.dat", ios::out | 
ios::binary);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                outdatabase.write(reinterpret_cast <const char *> 
(&blankelist), sizeof(employee));
            }
```

Section that adds a new record:

```
void newrecord(fstream &insertinfile) {

int id = getid("Enter new employee ID");

insertinfile.seekg((id - 1) * sizeof(employee));

employee employed;
insertinfile.read(reinterpret_cast <char *>(&employed), sizeof(employee));

if (employed.getId() == 0)
{
    string name;
    double salary;
    int year_hired;

    cout << "Enter name, balance, and year hired: " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cin >> salary;
    cin >> year_hired;

    employed.setname(name);
    employed.setSalary(salary);
    employed.setYearHired(year_hired);

    employed.setId(id);

    insertinfile.seekp((id- 1) * sizeof(employee));

    insertinfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *> (&employed), 
sizeof(employee));
}
else {
    cerr << "Employee ID: " << id
        << " already contains information." << endl;
}

}
```

I want to be able to turn the year_hired under struct into a string that stores a hire_date eventually with a string. I also want to change the salary into a string that can also be be shown up.

However, right now, I'm having an issue output the name from an account.

Do you guys have any tips on how to fix this issue with the character arrays? I've provided the code I have so far. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I was able to fix the issue with arrays by using the answer below

```
if (n.size() >= sizeof name) {
        cout << "Name " << n << " is too long\n";
    }
    else {
        strcpy_s(name, n.c_str());
    }
```

I'm still working on fixing the issue with updating a new record and saving changes. Thanks for your responses so far!

EDIT 2: Hey! I figured out the issue with updating an account.

This was issue #2 above. The code I had was

```
void updaterecord(fstream &updateFile) {

int id = getid("Enter account to update");
{

    updateFile.seekg((id - 1) * sizeof(employee));
    employee employed;
    updateFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char *> (&employed), sizeof(employee));

    if (employed.getId() != 0)
    {
        outputLine(cout, employed);

        cout << "\nEnter the new name, salary, and year hired: ";
        double salary;
        string name;
        int year_hired;
        cin >> name >> salary >> year_hired;

        double oldsalary = employed.getsal();

        employed.setname(name);
        employed.setSalary(salary);
        employed.setYearHired(year_hired);

        updateFile.seekp((id) * sizeof(employed));

    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Account # " << id << " has no information." << endl;
    }
}
}
```

To fix: I changed and added the following at the end of the function:

```
updateFile.seekp((id - 1) * sizeof(employee));
updateFile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&employed), 
sizeof(employee));
```

Comment: 1) "_which comes up with gibberish_" Don't post screenshots, when you could just as easily copy-paste. 2) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to figure out where your code does something you didn't expect? 3) "_I've provided the code I have so far below_" You aren't meant to provide full code. You need to provide manufactured [mcve] that reproduces the problem. This is way too much code to look through.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! I edited my post to provide more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't copy a C string using assignment to the pointer, you need to use `strcpy()`.

```
void setname(string n) {
    if (n.size() >= sizeof name) {
        cout << "Name " << n << " is too long\n";
    } else {
        strcpy(name, n.c_str());
    }
}
```

Also,

```
ptr = &name[30];
```

is a pointer to beyond the end of the `name` array. The last element of the array is `name[29]`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! I was having trouble figuring out how to use strcpy() .

Using that helped output the name when my program called the function.

Actually, when I used strcpy(), visual studio returned error 4996 again and told me to use strcpy_s() instead, just a heads up.

Thanks again for your response!

Comment: `strcpy_s()` is a Microsoft-specific extension.